# How to prove determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix that looks something like a Vandermonde matrix.

A = $\begin{bmatrix}a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4\\b & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 \\ c & c^2 & c^3 & c^4 \\ d& d^2 & d^3 & d^4 \end{bmatrix}$

I have currently performed row reduction by subtracting $R1$ from all other rows and then manually calculating the determinant and trying to simplify it but it looks wrong and tedious. Is there a better way to do it?

The answer seems to be $abcd(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)$

Comment: Scaling a single row by $a$ scales the determinant by $a$. Hence this comes exactly from the Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by scaling by a? You mean to divide it?

Comment: Row $1$ of the vandermont matrix is multiplied by $a$, row $2$ by $b$, etc.

Comment: One does not "prove" determinants. One computes them or proves some theorems about them.